# How to prevent vertical scroll on swipe left/right

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, swipe, ionic-framework

When I try to swipe left/right my app content also scrolls vertically creating messy UX. Is there a way to prevent it?

This is how I handle swipe

```
// angular directive
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $ionicGesture.on('swiperight', function(){console.log("swiped");}, element );
}
```

Comment: please check reformulated answer, and provide feedback when able...

Comment: @Manube sorry, i have no way/time of checking this anymore, i dont even use ionic now, let the community deal with it, there are quite a few interested people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FOREWORD: This solution was entirely rephrased after ensuring compatibility with both ios and android environments; comments below may no longer apply; any feedback is welcome.

---

**YES**, there is a way to prevent app content from scrolling when you swipe horizontally: by combining an angularjs `tapDetector` directive with ionic `$ionicScrollDelegate` service.

We will also need to detect the swipe using very fast dom events detection (`mousedown`/`touchstart`, `mousemove`/`touchmove`, `mouseup`/`touchend`);
it is necessary because `$ionicGesture` event listener detects the swipe after the scroll has been done: detection for swipe in ionic is to slow for our purpose.

---

The `tapDetector` directive is placed on body like so:

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl" tap-detector>
```

And here is the code for the directive:

```
.directive('tapDetector',function($ionicGesture,$ionicScrollDelegate){
  return{
    restrict:'EA',
    link:function(scope,element){
      var startX,startY,isDown=false;
      element.bind("mousedown touchstart", function(e){
        e=(e.touches)?e.touches[0]:e;//e.touches[0] is for ios
        startX = e.clientX;
        startY = e.clientY;
        isDown=true;
        //console.log("mousedown",startX,startY);
      });

      element.bind("mousemove touchmove", function(e){
        e=(e.touches)?e.touches[0]:e;//e.touches[0] is for ios
        if(isDown){
          var deltaX = Math.abs(e.clientX - startX);
                var deltaY = Math.abs(e.clientY - startY);

          if(deltaX > deltaY) {
          //console.log("horizontal move");
            $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').freezeScroll(true);
            }
        }
      });

      element.bind("mouseup touchend", function(e){
        isDown=false;
        $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').freezeScroll(false);
        //console.log("mouseup touchend");
      });
    }
  }
})
```

---

When you touch the screen (preparation for swipe), the coordinates of touch are set (startX, startY) and `isDown` is set to true.

When you start swiping, we need to determine whether swipe is horizontal or vertical. We are only interested in horizontal swipes:

```
var deltaX = Math.abs(e.clientX - startX);
var deltaY = Math.abs(e.clientY - startY);
```

`deltaX` is the difference (delta) between original X and current X;
`deltaY` is the difference (delta) between original Y and current Y;

```
if (deltaX > deltaY)
```

We got an horizontal swipe!

Now the swipe has been detected fast enough, all that is left to be done is to dynamically prevent the scroll:

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').freezeScroll(true);
```

and in the HTML: `<ion-content delegate-handle="mainScroll">`

---

After scroll is complete, we must un-freeze (thaw?) the scroll:

```
element.bind("mouseup touchend", function(e){
                    isDown=false;
                    $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').freezeScroll(false);
                });
```

---

This was tested with iPad 2
and Android Galaxy S4

---

Almost forgot: here is a [working pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByeWEa?editors=101) (courtesy of sMr)

Comment: @sMr since you opened a bounty please check this and tell me if it works so i can accept the answer.

Comment: @Anri i tried the answer but it frezee the content while swiping.. so lets wait for another answers until the last day of bounty

Comment: @sMr yes, I put an arbitrary delay of 3s before resuming normal scrolling behavior; it can be shortened as you wish, though; please specify what exact behavior you are expecting: right now vertical scrolling is prevented after a swipe has been triggered: isn't it what was required?

Comment: @Manube first of all i am using an  ion-list and each ion-item in the list has swipe left and right gestures. When you swipe left or right with not an exact horizantal line before swipe event being triggered the ion-list scrolls  this makes a little vertical scroll befere freeze  it

Comment: ok, I understand. You would need to stop the scroll just before the swipe, otherwise there is still some scrolling happening, correct?

Comment: @Manube yes  exactly. by the way i made a pen that desribes my problem http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoVxqj.

Comment: ok, thanks, got another idea, will try it in your pen (see updated answer)

Comment: @sMr thanks for the pen you provided. I now provided what I believe is a working solution (see edit); follow the link in the updated answer, as I forked your pen, the pen url is different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74425/discussion-between-smr-and-manube).

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no API from ionic team to do that, but i temporary made a monkey patch and feature request. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2703