# In Ionic, how to disable vertical scrolling while swiping left?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making a Ionic mobile app, whose main view is a vertical list of cards. I want each card to be "swipable", in the same way as Google Now cards.

I started to implement this:

```
$scope.onDrag = function(event, card){
    $scope.draggedStyle = {
        "left": (event.gesture.deltaX) + "px",
        "-webkit-transform": "translateZ(0)"
    };
}
```

The problem is that the user can scroll vertically while swiping the card. This is laggy and it's not the behavior I would expect.

Is there a way to disable vertical scroll only when the user is swiping a card?

**[edit]** I use native scrolling, not JS scrolling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use touchmove event to disable native scrolling. I took [beaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4432208/beaver)'s codepen as reference and added a touchmove event which checks for scroll object saved in local storage and disables scrolling if it is set to false.
It is working but it is also closing the ionic options buttons in this example. I am sure you can experiment with some other elements and figure it out.

```
 $window.localStorage["Scroll"] = JSON.stringify(true);
  angular.element($window).bind('touchmove', function(e) {

        var scroll = JSON.parse($window.localStorage["Scroll"]);

       if(!scroll)
       {
         e.preventDefault();
       }

     });

  $scope.disableVerticalScrolling = function() {
    console.log("disableVerticalScrolling");
    $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollView().options.scrollingY = false;
    $window.localStorage["Scroll"] = JSON.stringify(false);
  }

  $scope.enableVerticalScrolling = function() {
    console.log("enableVerticalScrolling");
    $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollView().options.scrollingY = true;
     $window.localStorage["Scroll"] = JSON.stringify(true);
  }
```

Here is the example 
http://codepen.io/kumar_garapati/pen/jWZMbL?editors=0010

you can read about more touchmove and native scrolling on following pages

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Prevent-Scrolling

http://blog.ionic.io/native-scrolling-in-ionic-a-tale-in-rhyme/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try inspiration by this [example](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/BymKOE) based on CSS:

```
.no-scroll{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

For example you could add the `no-scroll` class (using **ngClass**) during swipe-left operation.

Comment: This disables the vertical scroll AND the horizontal scroll. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `freezeScroll`. Refer to [How to disable content scrolling?](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-disable-content-scrolling/238/20) and [How to prevent vertical scroll on swipe left/right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345365/how-to-prevent-vertical-scroll-on-swipe-left-right)

Comment: I tried that but AFAIK freezeScroll only works with Javascript scrolling. I am using native scrolling (with overflow-scroll="true").

Answer (score -1):

Another approach uses [$ionicScrollDelegate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/) to enable/disable vertical scrolling when needed.

So, for example, in each `<ion-item>` add on-drag-left and on-drag-right event handlers:

```
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" 
              item="item"
              on-drag-left="disableVerticalScrolling()"
              on-drag-right="enableVerticalScrolling()"
    ...
```

In those handlers $ionicScrollDelegate is used as in code below:

```
  $scope.disableVerticalScrolling = function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollView().options.scrollingY = false;
  }

  $scope.enableVerticalScrolling = function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollView().options.scrollingY = true;
  }
```

These functions are also called when finished some operations done by option buttons (i.e. edit, delete, share, ...).

Here is an example showing this approach:

http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/XXVzXa?editors=101

Comment: I tried that but scrolling is not disabled. I assumed it was because I don't use Javascript scrolling. Do you know how can I understand why this does not work for me?

Comment: yes I think it depends on which type of scrolling you set... but you didn't say this in your question :(. I tried to set `$ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);` and it doesn't work any more

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to mention this. :/