# Ionic 2 - How do I disable scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

First of all: I know there are some topics about this already, but none of them seem to help me.

I tried all methods I could find to disable scrolling on one of my pages, but none of them work and so I come to seek help here.

What I tried:

- Creating a css class which hides overflow (same with attr.noScroll)
- setScrollDisabled
- set a div as ion-fixed
- ion-content no-bounce
- ::-webkit-scrollbar
- overflow-scroll="false"

---

This is what my page looks like ...

[It has this white bar on the bottom of the screen when I scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYxZB.jpg)

I only added a background picture whose width I set to 100% and height:auto (height: 100% produces the same white bar)

For reference, here is my code if it helps

```
<ion-content>
  <img class="bgc" src="assets/background.png">
</ion-content>
```

Comment: You can use touch move event to disable native scrolling. check this answer for more info  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34843680/in-ionic-how-to-disable-vertical-scrolling-while-swiping-left/34954513?noredirect=1#comment71234165_34954513

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix it, you should understand what's causing it, so you probably want to [`read this`](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

---

In some special cases, you might be able to hide that white space by disabling scrolling, but that's really not how you should approach this issue.
Instead, you should just remove the white space. You can do it by applying

```
display: block;
```

... or ...

```
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

to your `<img>` element.

As an alternative, you can change your markup to:

```
<ion-content>
  <img class="bgc" src="assets/background.png"
/></ion-content>
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it ... so would my "anti"-scroll css have actually worked if I did this from the start? (overflow-y: hidden;)

Comment: Nope. The *"space"* is proper content, so `overflow:hidden;` would not hide it. It's `tabs` + `new lines` + `spaces` reduced to a single space. Your `<img>` is a word. You want the spaces between your words rendered, right? The browser renders those spaces. Please read the link I provided, explaining why that space is there.

Comment: OK, thank you for the fast answers! I have read your link and I understand the space-content now.

Answer (score 3):

The scroll event cannot be canceled. But you can do it by canceling these interaction events:
Mouse & Touch scroll and Buttons associated with scrolling.

http://output.jsbin.com/xatidu/4/ <-- Working version

```
var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    }
}

function disableScroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
  window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // mobile
  document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}

function enableScroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener)
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null; 
    window.onwheel = null; 
    window.ontouchmove = null;  
    document.onkeydown = null;  
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it works!, but the answer above is cleaner for this particular problem. Although I will go back at this for other pages, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)